# Lua - check if user inputted table exists and read from it

Tags: function, variables, lua, key-value, lua-table

First, let me explain my setup. I have 2 lua files: one is the main program to run and the other is a configuration file. In the main program, it runs through the configuration file once and loads all the tables to memory. If I want to add a new configuration, I don't want to have to reprogram the main program, I want to be able to just add a new table in the configuration file.

The main program:

```
-- Read config
dofile("config.lua")

-- Ask for ID
inputtedID = io.read()
-- Check if it exists
if string.format("%s[enabled]", inputtedID) then
    -- If table exists and enabled key is set to true
    print('"' .. inputtedID .. '" does exist!')
else
    -- If the table doesn't exist or the key is false
    print('"' .. inputtedID .. '" does not exist')
end
```

The configuration file:

```
Public = {
enabled = true,
directory = "whatever"
}
Snapshot = {
enabled = true,
directory = "something"
}
-- So forth and so on
```

Each table will have the same keys to be read, but the one we need to focus on is the `enabled` key. Which brings us to this...

I want it to take the user input, check to see if there is a table that matches the user input, and check if the `enabled` key value in that table is `true`. If the table does not exist or the value is false, then just run a different set of code asking to retry.

And to be specific where I'm getting stuck, it's whenever I try using a variable when referring to or working with a table. I don't know how it can be done, nor do I know how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All global variables are members of the global table, called `_G`, which you can then index by the name of your variable:

```
-- Read config
dofile("config.lua")

-- Ask for ID
inputtedID = io.read()

-- Check if it exists
if _G[inputtedID] and _G[inputtedID].enabled then
    -- If table exists and enabled key is set to true
    print('"' .. inputtedID .. '" does exist!')
else
    -- If the table doesn't exist or the key is false
    print('"' .. inputtedID .. '" does not exist')
end
```